# Verificar pasta vazia em PHP

Tags: php

Preciso descobrir se uma pasta está vazia ou não usando PHP, pois possuo um sistema de cadastro de imagens, só que quando eu apago as imagens da pasta, ela continua lá.

Meu objetivo é sempre que não houver mais fotos na pasta ela seja automaticamente deletada, já pesquisei sobre e não achei nada que me ajudasse.

Exemplo fictício:

```
$ dir = 'pastaRaiz/dirTest';

if($dir == 'empty'){ 
  echo 'Diretório vazio deletado !';
  rmdir($dir)
}
```

Comment: Utilize rmdir($dir); Referência: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rmdir.php

Comment: Se geralmente o diretório contiver poucos arquivos, pode usar o [`scandir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php). Para diretórios com muitos arquivos, melhor usar os *file system iterators* do php.

Comment: Já consegui o que queria usando o scandir() .

Agradeço pela ajuda.

<?php
echo '<h1>Folder:</h1><br>'; 
$dir    = './Pasta teste';

$files1 = scandir($dir);
// $files2 = scandir($dir, 1);

print_r($files1);

echo "<br>";
echo $files1[3];
echo "<br>";

if(!$files1[3]){
    rmdir($dir);
    echo 'Pasta deletada !';
}else{

    echo "<br>";
    echo 'Arquivo com conteúdo';
}
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá tudo bem? A combinação das funções `count` e `glob` do PHP podem te ajudar nesta tarefa. Para isso você deve realizar a seguinte verificação:

```
<?php

    $empty = ((count(glob("$dir/*")) === 0) ? true : false);

?>
```

Depois, caso a variável `$empty` esteja retornando **`true`**, faça a exclusão da pasta desejada.